# VBA select vis cells only in range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select the first visible cell and the last visible cell.
I can select both first and last vis cell with lastrow2 and firstrow but when I try to have the whole range selected it's giving the error "runtime error 1004" and not sure why.

i know it's basic ..still learning :)

```
With ActiveSheet
 lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BH").End(xlUp).Row
        colI = Range("BH1").Column
   .Cells(lastrow2, colI).Select
   
    End With
    
With ActiveSheet
    
    firstrow = Range("BH1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End With

Set SelectVisCell = Worksheets("Tagged - All").Range(firstrow & lastrow2)
```

if i put the ranges in : `Set SelectVisCell = Worksheets("Tagged - All").Range("BH2:BL" & lastrow2)` - works like this, but this is not the first visible value.

Comment: `"BH" & firstrow & ":BL" & lastrow2` ?

Comment: I suspect you should look at the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method.